# Newtheoremstyle head aligned with top of tabularx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, theorems

Here's an example :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw, inner color = white, drop shadow = {opaque, black}, inner sep=3pt, text justified] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\hangindent=2em}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  {.8em}
  {\squared{\thmnumber{#2}}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r @{\hskip .4em} X}
        a) & This is a test. \\
        b) & This is a long test. \\
        c) & This is a very long test.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

What I want is the number of the exercise to be aligned with the *top* of the tabularx (question a)) instead of being aligned with the *middle* of the tabularx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `t` (top alignment) for the optional argument of `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw, inner color = white, drop shadow = {opaque, black}, inner sep=3pt, text justified] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\hangindent=2em}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  {.8em}
  {\squared{\thmnumber{#2}}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{r @{\hskip .4em} X}
        a) & This is a test. \\
        b) & This is a long test. \\
        c) & This is a very long test.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not related to the question, but to prevent an overfull `\hbox` you'll need to reduce the width for the `tabularx`.

Comment: You mean I should change the argument `\textwidth` when I use `\tabularx` ? Then how could I still have the width of the text without risking an overfull `\hbox` ?

Comment: @Amateur Yes, precisely that. Since you declared a `2em` hangindet for the `exercise` environment, you'll need `\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}[t]{r @{\hskip .4em} X}` to prevent the bad box in this case.